# Install wordpress on windows hosting

Tags: windows, wordpress, hosting

I'm trying to install wordpress on windows hosting but I get **500 - Internal server error**.

Can anyone please help what is the reason of this issue and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install PHP for IIS?

WordPress has published [instructions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#Easy_5_Minute_Wordpress_Installation_on_Windows) for installing on a Windows server.

Answer (score 0):

there is a product called "WAMP server" that can be used for this type of thing